# Google charts : date with json

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am using google charts and i have a problem to pass the date from php to javascript

I use this :

PHP :

```
$dataArray = array();
while ($resultat = $resultats->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
$thedate = "(".$year.", ".$month.")";
$fixe = "12";
$variable = "14";
$dataArray[] = array($thedate, (int) $fixe, (int) $variable);
```

JS :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Taux fixes');
data.addColumn('number', 'Taux variables');
data.addRows(<?php echo json_encode($dataArray); ?>);
```

The error is :
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value (2014, 1) does not match type date in column index 0

Does someone know how to send the date ? In which format ?
Google charts want a "new Date(2012, 03)" in JS

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using JSON, the proper format for dates is a string like this: `'Date(year, month, day)'` (note there is no `new` keyword used in the string), where `month` is zero-indexed (so January is `0` not `1`).  The only DataTable construction method that supports inputting dates in this fashion is passing a JSON representation of the DataTable directly to the constructor:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($dataTable, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```

This requires reconfiguring your PHP a bit to construct a proper DataTable JSON string.  You need to create an associative array with `'cols'` and `'rows'` keys.  The `'cols'` key sets the columns for your DataTable, and the `'rows'` key contains the rows of data:

```
$dataTable = array (
    'cols' => array (
        array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Date'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Taux fixes'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Taux variables')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);
while ($resultat = $resultats->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // put results in $year, $month, $fixe, $variable

    $month = $month - 1; // correcting for javascript's 0-indexed months
    $dataTable['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => "Date($year, $month, 1)"),
        array('v' => $fixe),
        array('v' => $variable)
    ));
}
```